# Can I use Weapon Finesse to make Eldritch Glaive attacks using Dex?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, touch-attacks, warlock

Eldritch Glaive from Dragon Magic allows a Warlock to modify his Eldritch Blast attack:

> Your eldritch blast takes on physical substance, appearing similar to a glaive. As a full-round action, you can make a single melee touch attack as if wielding a reach weapon. If you hit, your target is affected as if struck by your eldritch blast (including any eldritch essence applied to the blast). Unlike hideous blow (Complete Arcane 134), you cannot combine your eldritch glaive with damage from a held weapon.
>   Furthermore, until the start of your next turn, you also threaten nearby squares as if wielding a reach weapon, and you can make attacks of opportunity with your eldritch glaive. These are melee touch attacks.
>   If your base attack bonus is +6 or higher, you can (as part of the full-round action) make as many attacks with your eldritch glaive as your base attack bonus allows. For example, a 12th-level warlock could attack twice, once with a base attack bonus of +6, and again with a base attack bonus of +1.

Complete Arcane p73 mentions that

> Weapon Finesse:
>   You can treat touch spells as light weapons and use your Dexterity modifier (instead of your Strength modifier) on your touch attack rolls with such spells.

And since Eldritch Blast is an (Sp) so I would assume that it works. Does it?

Are there any clarifications or additional official rules on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complete Arcane's rules for Weaponlike Spells specify that all weaponlike spells are finessable (may use dex instead of str to hit with the Weapon Finesse feat).

Eldritch Blast is a weaponlike spell explicitly, and Eldritch Glaive is a Blast Essence Invocation - it modifies, but does not change anything it doesn't say it changes, the properties of Eldritch Blast.

Ergo, by RAW, Eldritch Glaive is finessable.  But not due to it being a 'touch spell', which it's unclear if it is, but rather due to the specific rules in Complete Arcane.

Answer (score 6):

Page 71 of Complete Arcane specifies that *eldritch blast* is weaponlike. As eldritch glaive is a blast shape and thus an extension to the *eldritch blast* ability, it is also weaponlike and thus usable with Weapon Finesse.